# Enable/force featuretools to use 2 or more columns to group by

Tags: featuretools

How to enable or force featuretools to create featuretools groupby features using 2 or more columns as group bys.

For example I have columns x, y, z

how to set groupby_primitives_options or something to get feature `func(func(x) groupby y, z)` ?

Answer (score 0):

`groupby_primitive_options` does not currently support grouping by 2 or more columns, but you could write a custom primitive that does additional groupby operations inside the primitive function.

This may not directly apply to your situation, but in this [user issue](https://github.com/alteryx/featuretools/issues/1769) grouping by multiple columns was achieved by adding an intermediate table to the entityset.